# How to reduce the noise from a mechanical-switch keyboard?

Tags: sound

Some keys on the keyboard of my laptop don't work anymore. I have an external mechanical-switch keyboard so I just bring it with me and connect it to my laptop via USB for use. Unfortunately, this keyboard (with Cherry MX Brown switches) produces a fair amount of noise. When I use it during classes/at work, some people are quite unhappy with the noise.

Is there anything I can do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

A (very) few mechanical keyboards once had "switchable" clicks -- they actually used silent switches, and separate mechanical "clickers" that could be moved out of contact with the keys with a mechanical linkage.  If yours isn't one of those, it's impractical to silence it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use o-rings like the [ones sold by WASD](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/products/keyboard-accessories/cherry-mx-rubber-o-ring-switch-dampeners-125pcs.html) and put them on underneath the keycaps. It won't totally get rid of the noise but should help some.

Answer (score 2):

I have MX Brown switches at home and have never thought that they were over clicky, and to my dismay, at another situation, I could see how they could get annoying to other people. I remember seeing key silencers on Massdrop recently, but the drop has ended.

I am not sure what the rules are for linking to products, so if you use your favorite search provider and look for "Clip Sound Dampening Brackets" you should find something that might help. I have no experience with the product, but they claim 10dB in attenuation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Silicone keyboard cover,
Work like a sponge between your fingers and the keys, and cover the mechanic parts, that's will reduce the sounds.

[image: Silicone Keyboard cover]

Answer (score -1):

Even on the laptop the keyboard is mechanical.  You mean external.

Take it apart to try and make it quiet is not likely to work.

Why not just buy a new keyboard for the laptop?   You probably paid more for the external Bluetooth.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53645/discussion-on-answer-by-paparazzi-how-to-reduce-the-noise-from-a-mechanical-swit).